# Как убить команду taskkill?

Tags: windows

**Попробовал как-то раз убить питон командой:** taskkill /f /im  Python.exe

**Теперь не могу перезапустить проводник:** taskkill /f /im  explorer.exe

**Выдает:** (taskkill /f /im  Python.exe) и в беcконечный цикл...

Как это можно исправить? перезагрузка ПК не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никто с таким не сталкивался?

Comment: Как это перезагрузка не помогает? Ты убил питон или проводник?

Comment: @don Rumata, раньше временами убивал проводник, команда срабатывала, но после того как я попытался убить питон команда убить питон ушла в цикл. Команда убить проводник теперь запускает убить питон в цикле. Что за шляпа не пойму.

Comment: Кинь скрин из `procexp` как это всё работает.

Comment: @don Rumata, добавил то что происходит в консоли. Что именно из procexp необходимо сфоткать пришлите пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пробовал завершить дерево процессов, эффекта нет.

Comment: если после ребута всё-равно запускается - смотри, что лежит в автозагрузке (раздел Run в реестре).

Comment: @PRODIGY, он не запускается автоматически после перезагрузки, но я не могу убить процесс эксплорера, при запуске команды вместо этого идет попытка убить питон... Поискал, ничего не нашел, да и не будет там... Есть подозрение что нужно копать в планировщик задач... либо в список запущенных процессов в коммандной строке.

Comment: Вс дерево приложи. Зачем скрин, где ты сто раз вызваешь одно и тоже?

Comment: да блин в том то и дело что я вызываю 1 раз команду убить эксплорер, он не убивает его, но вместо этого выдает цикл таких записей.... пока не остановишь...

Comment: в планировщике задач ничего не нашел, попробовал команду с питоном в командной строке пользователя и администратора, все аналогично. в PowerShell работает нормально.

Comment: В общем заметил одну особенность. я создал файл. taskkill.bat. Содержимое: taskkill /f /im Notepad2.exe   pause. Если запускаю от администратора, то команда если находит процесс, завершает его. Если запустить от пользователя, то такая же шляпа. причем то что я запускаю убить експлорер, содержимое зависит от того что последним я запускал от пользователя, то есть можно изменить.

Comment: Как я понимаю команда 'wmic ' то же может удалять процессы, wmic process where "name='myprocessname.exe'" delete, никто не знает есть ли там список команд которые запущены, но не выполнены?

Comment: cmd.exe запускает последнюю команду которую я использовал от имени пользователя. просто bat файл с командой pause так же становится последней запущенной, за исключением того что пропал цикл, новые команды так же не запустить.

Comment: Команда taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq %username%" от администратора не помогла...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в имени самого файла...

**Никогда не создавайте на рабочем столе файл с именем taskkill.bat !!!**